# How to revoke a permanent Facebook 'page' token with API v2.2?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I've created an application that only stores Facebook Page tokens. My application publishes content to pages.

I'm migrating from v1.0 to v2.2. I *used* to revoke Page tokens by calling a `DELETE` on `/me/permissions`. But now the API returns:

> Unsupported delete request. Please read the Graph API documentation
>   at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

How can I delete a **page** token with the new v2.2 Graph API?

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/permissions#delete removing permissions this way should still be possible. What does the exact API call you’re making look like, and what type of access token are you using?

Comment: Or are you trying to do this _using_ a page access token, so that `/me` would refer to the page? For pages there is no `/permissions` edge documented, not even in the v1 documentation.

Comment: Come to think of it, it is strange that it has worked. Only user tokens should be revocable. Page tokens don't mean anything because they are granted by the user. If the user token still exists, nothing stops the application from issuing it again without user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page tokens are not revocable. Only user tokens are revocable.

Comment: Where is this documented by Facebook?

Comment: Then what to do if that token was compromised?

Answer (score 1):

This is not done via the API, but as the page admin, you can revoke access previously granted to an app. You do so via your profile settings on a section called business tools. This section allows you to view apps with access and revoke their access, immediately invalidating page access tokens granted by you to that app.

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=business_tools

Answer (score 0):

I'd file a bug if there is a feature in 1.0 that hasn't been listed as removed in the change log.

On the other hand, I've never heard of such a call. If it existed, it's either a really old call or a bug in the API.

If you revoke a fan page token, how would you reissue it?

The only token you can revoke to my knowledge is the user token.

In addition, I tested a few 1.0 applications and no such call exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that.
You can force signing APIs that use your APP tokens; this way, even if the tokens got compromised, they can't use them without your app secret (you can easily reset your app secret from the app settings)

```
$time = time();
$appsecret_proof= hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token.'|'.$time, $app_secret); 
curl \
  -F 'access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=$appsecret_proof' \
  -F 'appsecret_time=$time' \
```

See this for more details
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#proof